# Plot from cartesian to polar coordinates using ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot my data using ListDensityPlot. But when I plot them. I succeeded to have my data in polar cooridnates but in the middle around zero all my data are white which should not be (see picture)...I don't see what I miss in my `ListDensityPlot`

[image: results]

Here my code and link with my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okddxag0khzezdq/2D_over2pi_0T.dat?dl=0)

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
file = "2D_over2pi_0T.dat";
data = Import[file, "Table", HeaderLines -> 2];
dataT = Transpose[data];
dataT = {N[ArcTan[dataT[[2]]*10, dataT[[1]]*10]/Degree], 
  Sqrt[(dataT[[2]]*10)^2 + (dataT[[1]]*10)^2], 
  dataT[[3]]}; (*convert my data in polar coordinates: theta,r,Z*)
data = Transpose[dataT];



Table[MapAt[#^(1/\[Gamma]) &, Brown, ;; 3], {\[Gamma], {0.4, 1, 2.2}}];
    gamma[\[Gamma]_][c_?ColorQ] := 
  MapAt[#1^(1/\[Gamma]) &, ColorConvert[c, "RGB"], ;; 3];
myTM[\[Gamma]_] := 
  gamma[\[Gamma]]@
    Blend[{{-1`, RGBColor[0.72, 1., 1.]}, {0`, RGBColor[
       1., 0.85, 1.]}, {0.1`, RGBColor[1., 0.98, 0.1]}, {0.5`, 
       RGBColor[1., 0.8200000000000001, 0.1]}, {1`, RGBColor[
       1., 0.49, 0.1]}, {3`, RGBColor[1., 0.28, 0.1]}, {8`, RGBColor[
       0.81, 0.06, 0]}}, #] &;



ListDensityPlot[({#[[2]] Cos[#[[1]]], #[[2]] Sin[#[[1]]], #[[3]]} &) /@
   data, ColorFunction -> myTM[0.28]]
```

Comment: The data which is equally spaced in Cartesian space is not equally spaced in Polar coordinates. This is reason why you have the decreasing point density when go to (0,0).

Comment: Thanks, what I should do to fix this problem ?

Comment: @Rom38 Actually the problem is that around the origin the values are high and M automatically clips them. Set `PlotRange -> All` to include the whole range.

Comment: The default clipping style is white, but `ClippingStyle -> Green` would make it obvious what is happening.